# Create Fluffy Blocks

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

(*randomly inspired by [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/2633)*)

Let's make a drawing from some pipes `|` and hyphens `-`. Choosing a subset, if chosen carefully, you can form a rectangular box or block shape (meaning that the corners are formed by `|-` or `-|`). For this challenge, we're concerned only with identifying the corners -- the vertical and horizontal pieces of the block shape can be made of either `|` or `-`, and the block may be hollow.

Here's the original drawing, and the subset showing a block shape.

```
|--|---|     |--|---|
|-|||-|| --> |      |
|------|     |------|
```

However, note that the following subsets from this same example do *not* make a block, because the corners are not all `-|` or `|-`

```
|--|
|-||

||-||
----|

|-|
---
```

Each combination of `-|` or `|-` can only form one corner. This means that the smallest possible block shape is these eight characters

```
|--|
|--|
```

and that these six characters do *not* form a block shape, since the corners are being "doubled up."

```
|-|
|-|
```

The challenge here is to turn these blocks fluffy. How? Replace every hard-edged straight character that forms the block edges (both corners and sides) with a much rounder, fluffier character, in this case, an `o`. But, don't fill in the block - we only want to get rid of the hard edges and sharp corners.

```
|--|---|     oooooooo
|-|||-|| --> o-|||-|o
|------|     oooooooo
```

#### Input

A 2D string representation of the pipe/hyphen diagram. Input can be as a multiline string, an array of strings, etc., however is [convenient for your language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963). The input is guaranteed to be rectangular (i.e., every row will be the same length), and will only contain `|` and `-`.

#### Output

The same diagram, with the "block" characters replaced with `o` as described above and the remaining characters unchanged. The result can be printed to the screen or STDOUT, returned from a function, etc.

#### Rules

- Note that blocks can overlap (see example #8) and blocks can share corners (see example #5).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

#### Examples

```
#1
-|--|
|--|-
|--||

-|--|
oooo-
oooo|

#2
|--|---|
|-|||-||
|------|

oooooooo
o-|||-|o
oooooooo

#3
|||||

|||||

#4
|-----|
||---|-
||---|-
|-----|

ooooooo
ooooooo
ooooooo
ooooooo

#5
-|--|--|
|||-|--|
-|-----|

-ooooooo
|o|-oooo
-ooooooo

#6
|-||-|
|----|

oooooo
oooooo

#7
--|--|-
|-----|

--|--|-
|-----|

#8
|-----|---
||--||-|--
||||--|--|
|-|-||||-|
|--|--|-||
---||---||
---|-----|

ooooooo---
o|--||o|--
o||ooooooo
o-|o||o|-o
ooooooo-|o
---o|---|o
---ooooooo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Perl, 448 bytes

```perl
$_=<>;$o=$_;~y/-|/Aa/;$N=$_;while($n ne $N){$n=$N;$c=$N;$M=$c;while($c=~s/^(.*?;)??([aA]*?)aA([aA]*)Aa(.*;(?i)\2)aA((?i)\3)Aa(.*)$/\L\1\2\UAA\3AA\L\4\UAA\5AA\L\6/){if($N eq $n){substr($N,(length $1)+(length $2),1)="X"}substr($M,-(length $6)-1,1)="X";$c=~s/^([xa;]*;)?(a*)A(A*)A(a*;)\2a((?i)\3)a/\1\2A\3A\4\2A\5A/;1 while $c=~s/(^|;)(a*)A(a*)A(a*;)\2a((?i)\3)a/\1\2A\3A\4\2A\5A/;while($c=~/A/g){substr($o,(pos $c)-1,1)="o"}$c=$M}}$o=~y/;/\n/;print$o
```

I haven't used perl before so there's going to be *massive* room for improvement here (especially since I was mostly glad to get it working, so haven't tried to optimise it yet). I was a bit disappointed that **the** regular expression language didn't have some of the features I wanted, but I think it does pretty well.

#### Usage

Takes input on stdin, with lines semicolon-separated (optionally add a semicolon to the end to make the final printed output end with a newline). Outputs to stdout. Example command:

```sh
printf -- "-|--|--|;|||-|--|;-|-----|;" | perl boxes.perl
```

#### Breakdown

```perl
$_=<>; # Load input
$o=$_; # Create output variable
~y/-|/Aa/; # Replace - and | with A and a so that we can use case insensitive tricks later
$N=$_;
# For each distinct top-left corner...
while($n ne $N){
    $n=$N;
    $c=$N;
    $M=$c;
    # For each distinct box...
    while($c=~s/^(.*?;)??([aA]*?)aA([aA]*)Aa(.*;(?i)\2)aA((?i)\3)Aa(.*)$/\L\1\2\UAA\3AA\L\4\UAA\5AA\L\6/){
        if($N eq $n){
            # mark top-left corner used (x)
            substr($N,(length $1)+(length $2),1)="X"
        }
        # mark bottom-right corner used (x)
        substr($M,-(length $6)-1,1)="X";

        # Fill in sides of identified box
        $c=~s/^([xa;]*;)?(a*)A(A*)A(a*;)\2a((?i)\3)a/\1\2A\3A\4\2A\5A/;
        1 while $c=~s/(^|;)(a*)A(a*)A(a*;)\2a((?i)\3)a/\1\2A\3A\4\2A\5A/;

        # Replace output chars with "o" where box was found
        while($c=~/A/g){
            substr($o,(pos $c)-1,1)="o"
        }

        # Continue to next box
        $c=$M
    }
}

# Convert to nice output & print
$o=~y/;/\n/;
print$o
```

Comment: If anybody knows how to make perl loop through all possible matching groups (as opposed to just the non-overlapping matches), it would save the need for both while loops and all the "x" logic.